# How to display the keys from a Firebase Database with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter

I have a simple Firebase Database which looks like this:

[image]

Using the code below, I managed to display the lists aaa, bbb, ddd and zzz into a `ListView` using `FirebaseListAdapter`.

```
listDatabaseReference = userDatabaseReference.child("Lists");
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDatabaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String string, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(string);
        }
    };
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

I also added a `setOnItemClickListener` and when an item is clicked, a `Toast` appears like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String string = firebaseListAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

With this code: `String string = firebaseListAdapter.getItem(position);`, I get the name of the List. Is there any possibility, instead of getting the name of the list, to get the corresponding key?

Lets say, instead of `aaa` to get `-Kc571TvSsoiYuMjPZ6d`. I really need that key.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

inside your addValueEventlistener add following

//Create a Arraylist of Strings globally say KEYS

{

```
    for (  DataSnapshot  postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) 
      {
       KEYS.add(postSnapshot.getKey());

      }
```

}
Now KEYS will contain all the keys